# How can I get the aliens to start doing abductions again?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I find it a lot of fun to pause my store progression at the Gollop chamber and just pass the in-game months fighting aliens, minmaxing my soldiers and experimenting with different teams; however I am finding that the game is missing something - I am no longer offered alien abductions to deal with. The Wikia site for the game says that abductions don't happen in countries with satellite coverage and stop altogether when *most* countries are covered with satellites, which is a good lead, but not nearly specific enough. What exact conditions stop alien abductions? Can I get alien abductions back after getting rid of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you let a UFO go by without intercepting it, it's likely a battleship will come by later and shoot down a satellite.

If you have at least two countries uncovered by satellites, you'll get abduction missions.

So, you can wait for the aliens to shoot down two of your satellites and then abduction missions should start appearing again.

Comment: This is probably the only way to get them back. Disadvantage : when a satellite is shot down, that country tends to go into panic. So you may lose a few nations from the programme.

Comment: So, can abductions happen in lost countries? Shouldn't it be "Abductions can happen when you have two countries uncovered by satellites _and_ not withdrawn from the council."?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but could you also just destroy a sat uplink to lose sat coverage, instead of waiting for a shoot-down?

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm this works.

I left one country (Egypt) in my home continent (Africa) without a satellite hoping to continue getting abduction missions. This didn't work however.

I then let a UFO escape and a Battleship turned up later and I left this alone too. It shot down the satellite over Russia.

Russia went up to a panic level of 5 because of this. Shortly afterwards however I got a Bomb disposal mission in Russia which reduced panic levels and then an UFO landing.

The next mission after that was an Abduction mission as you can see:

[image: Re-instated Abduction Missions]

This leads me to think when playing Iron-man it may be worth leaving the remaining countries in your home continent without satellites. The extra cash, meld and rewards would be a decent boost. That is assuming they don't replace normal UFO missions which they may well do.